# Fancyhdr does not work!

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to compile my code using `fancyhdr` package but it doesn't compile it properly. Can someone kindly advise how to fix the issue?
Here is what I am compiling:

```
% MNRAS Manuscript Template
\documentclass[useams,onecolumn,usenatbib,twoside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lettrine}
%
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}

\hypersetup{final}
\hypersetup{citecolor=CornflowerBlue}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=CornflowerBlue}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=CornflowerBlue}
\def\Planck{\,{\em Planck}}
\def\ie{\,{\rm i.e.}\,}
\def\eg{\,{\rm e.g.}\,}
\def\um{{\rm $\mu$m}\,}
\def\sdss{{\sc sdss}}
\def\viking{{\sc viking}}
\def\hatlas{{\sc h-atlas}}
\def\wise{{\em WISE}}
\def\vista{{\sc vista}}
\def\galex{{\em GALEX}}
\def\lambdar{{\sc lambdar}}
\def\lamsc{{\sc lambdar}}
\def\magphys{{\sc magphys}}
\def\interest{{\sc interest}}
\def\bbf{}
%

\newcommand\aap{A\&A}                % Astronomy and Astrophysics
\let\astap=\aap                          % alternative shortcut
\newcommand\aapr{A\&ARv}             % Astronomy and Astrophysics Review (the)
\newcommand\aaps{A\&AS}              % Astronomy and Astrophysics Supplement Series
\newcommand\actaa{Acta Astron.}      % Acta Astronomica
\newcommand\afz{Afz}                 % Astrofizika
\newcommand\aj{AJ}                   % Astronomical Journal (the)
\newcommand\ao{Appl. Opt.}           % Applied Optics
\let\applopt=\ao                         % alternative shortcut
\newcommand\aplett{Astrophys.~Lett.} % Astrophysics Letters
\newcommand\apj{ApJ}                 % Astrophysical Journal
\newcommand\apjl{ApJ}                % Astrophysical Journal, Letters
\let\apjlett=\apjl                       % alternative shortcut
\newcommand\apjs{ApJS}               % Astrophysical Journal, Supplement
\let\apjsupp=\apjs                       % alternative shortcut
% The following journal does not appear to exist! Disabled.
%\newcommand\apspr{Astrophys.~Space~Phys.~Res.} % Astrophysics Space Physics Research
\newcommand\apss{Ap\&SS}             % Astrophysics and Space Science
\newcommand\araa{ARA\&A}             % Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics
\newcommand\arep{Astron. Rep.}       % Astronomy Reports
\newcommand\aspc{ASP Conf. Ser.}     % ASP Conference Series
\newcommand\azh{Azh}                 % Astronomicheskii Zhurnal
\newcommand\baas{BAAS}               % Bulletin of the American Astronomical Society
\newcommand\bac{Bull. Astron. Inst. Czechoslovakia} % Bulletin of the Astronomical Institutes of Czechoslovakia
\newcommand\bain{Bull. Astron. Inst. Netherlands} % Bulletin Astronomical Institute of the Netherlands
\newcommand\caa{Chinese Astron. Astrophys.} % Chinese Astronomy and Astrophysics
\newcommand\cjaa{Chinese J.~Astron. Astrophys.} % Chinese Journal of Astronomy and Astrophysics
\newcommand\fcp{Fundamentals Cosmic Phys.}  % Fundamentals of Cosmic Physics
\newcommand\gca{Geochimica Cosmochimica Acta}   % Geochimica Cosmochimica Acta
\newcommand\grl{Geophys. Res. Lett.} % Geophysics Research Letters
\newcommand\iaucirc{IAU~Circ.}       % IAU Cirulars
\newcommand\icarus{Icarus}           % Icarus
\newcommand\japa{J.~Astrophys. Astron.} % Journal of Astrophysics and Astronomy
\newcommand\jcap{J.~Cosmology Astropart. Phys.} % Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics
\newcommand\jcp{J.~Chem.~Phys.}      % Journal of Chemical Physics
\newcommand\jgr{J.~Geophys.~Res.}    % Journal of Geophysics Research
\newcommand\jqsrt{J.~Quant. Spectrosc. Radiative Transfer} % Journal of Quantitiative Spectroscopy and Radiative Transfer
\newcommand\jrasc{J.~R.~Astron. Soc. Canada} % Journal of the RAS of Canada
\newcommand\memras{Mem.~RAS}         % Memoirs of the RAS
\newcommand\memsai{Mem. Soc. Astron. Italiana} % Memoire della Societa Astronomica Italiana
\newcommand\mnassa{MNASSA}           % Monthly Notes of the Astronomical Society of Southern Africa
\newcommand\mnras{MNRAS}             % Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society
%\newcommand\na{New~Astron.}          % New Astronomy
\newcommand\nar{New~Astron.~Rev.}    % New Astronomy Review
\newcommand\nat{Nature}              % Nature
\newcommand\nphysa{Nuclear Phys.~A}  % Nuclear Physics A
\newcommand\phdt{PhD.T}        % PhD Thesis
\newcommand\pra{Phys. Rev.~A}        % Physical Review A: General Physics
\newcommand\prb{Phys. Rev.~B}        % Physical Review B: Solid State
\newcommand\prc{Phys. Rev.~C}        % Physical Review C
\newcommand\prd{Phys. Rev.~D}        % Physical Review D
\newcommand\pre{Phys. Rev.~E}        % Physical Review E
\newcommand\prl{Phys. Rev.~Lett.}    % Physical Review Letters
\newcommand\pasa{Publ. Astron. Soc. Australia}  % Publications of the Astronomical Society of Australia
\newcommand\pasp{PASP}               % Publications of the Astronomical Society of the Pacific
\newcommand\pasj{PASJ}               % Publications of the Astronomical Society of Japan
\newcommand\physrep{Phys.~Rep.}      % Physics Reports
\newcommand\physscr{Phys.~Scr.}      % Physica Scripta
\newcommand\planss{Planet. Space~Sci.} % Planetary Space Science
\newcommand\procspie{Proc.~SPIE}     % Proceedings of the Society of Photo-Optical Instrumentation Engineers
\newcommand\rmxaa{Rev. Mex. Astron. Astrofis.} % Revista Mexicana de Astronomia y Astrofisica
\newcommand\qjras{QJRAS}             % Quarterly Journal of the RAS
\newcommand\sci{Science}             % Science
\newcommand\skytel{Sky \& Telesc.}   % Sky and Telescope
\newcommand\solphys{Sol.~Phys.}      % Solar Physics
\newcommand\sovast{Soviet~Ast.}      % Soviet Astronomy (aka Astronomy Reports)
\newcommand\ssr{Space Sci. Rev.}     % Space Science Reviews
\newcommand\zap{Z.~Astrophys.}       % Zeitschrift fuer Astrophysik

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        %\vskip 40\p@
        \vskip 100\p@
}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        %\vskip 40\p@
        \vskip 100\p@
}}
%%%%%
\makeindex{}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.gif,.jpg}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Title Page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}



    \textsc {\LARGE The University of NoWhere}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc {\LARGE  \& }\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{School of SomeWhere}\\[0.5cm]
    \LARGE PhD Thesis\\[0.5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries
My thesis title
}\\[0.4cm]
    \HRule \\[0.5cm]


% Author and supervisor
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
Stranger
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisors:} \\
Prof. Z.\\
A/Prof. A \\
Dr. B.
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

 \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./images/logo.png}
 \end{minipage} \\[0.5cm]

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today}

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Preamble
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\include{Preamble}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\include{ChapterOne}
\include{ChapterTwo}
\include{ChapterThree}
\include{ChapterFour}
\include{ChapterFive}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{library}
\appendix
\include{AppendixOne}
\include{AppendixTwo}
\include{AppendixThree}
\printindex{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiling your example with `pdflatex`, I have the following error: `! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./images/logo.png' not found.` (which is normal since I don't have your file logo.png)
When commenting out this, the compilation ends without error. Could you please be more explicit about your error?

Comment: I compiled it with pdflatex as you advised and it is compiled with no error! But still I can't see any header.

Comment: There are hundreds of document classes called Thesis.cls (but none in standard distributions such as texlive) please link to the one you are using, I note you are using `\rm` which has not been defined by default in LaTeX since 1993, so if the error you get is that `\rm`  and `\sc` are undefined, that would be why.

Comment: Unrelated but `\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}` is nonsense. Your file can't have two input encodings at the same time.

Comment: You are using `\pagestyle{plain}`, and plain style has no header.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike Fischer. Good catch! That works now.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `\pagestyle{plain}`, and plain style has no header.